# regroup after unwind of subdocument of subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my Document.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("589b6132fafb5a09549b46cb"), 
    "name" : "foo", 
    "users" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("589b6132fafb5a09549b46cc"), 
            "name" : "Peter", 
            "emails" : [
                {
                    "address" : "peter@email.com"
                }, 
                {
                    "address" : "test2@email.com"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("589b6132fafb5a09549b46cd"), 
            "name" : "Joe", 
            "emails" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm unwinding users and users.email
And when I try to regroup, I get a duplicate on user named Peter because it has 2 emails.

Query:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": {
    "path": "$users",
    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
  } },
  { "$unwind": {
    "path": "$users.emails",
    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
  } },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "name": { "$first": "$name" },
      "users": { "$addToSet": "$users"},
      "allEmails": { "$push": "$users.emails.address" }
    }
  }
])
```

Result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("589b6132fafb5a09549b46cb"), 
    "name" : "foo", 
    "users" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("589b6132fafb5a09549b46cd"), 
            "name" : "Joe"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("589b6132fafb5a09549b46cc"), 
            "name" : "Peter", 
            "emails" : {
                "address" : "test2@email.com"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("589b6132fafb5a09549b46cc"), 
            "name" : "Peter", 
            "emails" : {
                "address" : "peter@email.com"
            }
        }
    ], 
    "allEmails" : [
        "peter@email.com", 
        "test2@email.com"
    ]
}
```

I need the users object to be exact the same before the unwind with allEmails on the document parent as shown in the following example.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("589b6132fafb5a09549b46cb"), 
    "name" : "foo", 
    "users" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("589b6132fafb5a09549b46cc"), 
            "name" : "Peter", 
            "emails" : [
                { "address" : "test2@email.com" },
                { "address" : "peter@email.com" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("589b6132fafb5a09549b46cd"), 
            "name" : "Joe", 
            "emails" : []
        }
    ], 
    "allEmails" : [
        "peter@email.com", 
        "test2@email.com"
    ]
}
```

Comment: MongoDB Version: 3.4

Comment: You can try something like this `db.collection.distinct("users.emails", {"_id" : ObjectId("589b6132fafb5a09549b46cb")});` if you are okay with this response `[
        {
                "address" : "peter@email.com"
        },
        {
                "address" : "test2@email.com"
        }
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the following aggregate pipeline should give you the desired result:

```
db.test.aggregate([   
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "allEmails": { 
                "$reduce": {
                    "input": {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": "$users",
                            "as": "user",
                            "in": "$$user.emails"
                        }
                    },
                    "initialValue": [],
                    "in": { "$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this.address"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }     
])
```

---

The above pipeline works by initially creating a two dimensional array of emails addresses objects using **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)**. To show an example result produced by apply the expression

```
{
    "$map": {
        "input": "$users",
        "as": "user",
        "in": "$$user.emails"
    }
}
```

run a test pipeline with just a single field that holds the results:

```
db.test.aggregate([   
    {
        "$project": {
            "twoDarray": { 
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$users",
                        "as": "user",
                        "in": "$$user.emails"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }     
])
```

which will produce the 2D array

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("589b6132fafb5a09549b46cb"),
    "twoDarray" : [ 
        [ 
            { "address" : "peter@email.com" }, 
            { "address" : "test2@email.com" }
        ], 
        []
    ]
}
```

Now, denormalise this 2-D array

```
[ 
    [ 
        { "address" : "peter@email.com" }, 
        { "address" : "test2@email.com" }
    ], 
    []
]
```

by using the **[`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce)** operator which applies an expression to each element in an array and combines them into a single value. With the help of the **[`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/#exp._S_concatArrays)** operator, you can concatenate each element within the **[`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce)** expression to form the final desired array

```
[
    "peter@email.com", 
    "test2@email.com"
]
```